# call delegate method in class extension, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have UITextField class extension:

```
extension UITextField {
    ...
}
```

Also class UITextField have protocol:

```
protocol UITextFieldDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    . . .
    optional func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool // return NO to not change text
    . . .
}
```

How I can use "protocol method" OR "how can I detect change characters" in my extension?

-

My main goal is detect character changed range.

Comment: Are you trying to get notified when a text field is changed and what text is changing, or are you trying to add your own functionality to replace `textField(_ , shouldChangeCharactersInRange, replacementString)`?

Comment: I want in any way detect changing characters in the field. UITextField  allow to use this 3 notifications: `let UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification: NSString!
let UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification: NSString!
let UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification: NSString!` but this is not enough. My main goal is detect character changed range. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You want the protocol method in this case. You can set the textFields's delegate to your view controller and then it will tell you anytime the text is changed and what it was changed to. Be sure to declare your that your view controller implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods. Here is an example view controller that detects text field changes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this allows the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method to be called
        self.textField.delegate = self  
    }

    // UITextFieldDelegate method
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // range is the range of which characters changed
        // string is the characters that will replace the textField.text's characters in the given range
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is right direction. But now I have another problem: -- When I create my subclass in separate file with UITextFieldDelegate protocol and use proper method. All works. But if somebody wants to use UITextFieldDelegate in ex. ViewController class, my protocol method will be override by new.

Comment: I need more detail. Is the subclass ViewController? And are there multiple text fields connected to ViewController that will all rely on `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`?

Comment: Thx for your help. Here is new question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928392/call-protocol-method-twice-swift