# Call protocol method twice, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have subclass file which use method from UITextFieldDelegate protocol

```
class MyTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
     . . .
     override func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
         super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)

         self.delegate = self       
     }

     func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

         // some actions

         return true
     }
}
```

In my ViewController class I use input field with my subclass

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var field: MyTextFieldMask!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          self.field.delegate = self

     }
     func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

         // some other actions

         return true
     }
}
```

---

If somebody add UITextFieldDelegate protocol method to ViewController class (like on code above) my first method in MyTextField subclass will be overwritten.

How I can use same method twice with different actions inside?

Comment: Thats not the same class, above its MyTextField and below it is MyTextFieldMask.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it through if you want it to execute. You'll need to implement all of the delegate protocol methods, even if they just end up being pass-throughs. Example:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

     // some other actions

     self.field.textField(self.field, range, string)

     return true
 }
```

Making an object be a delegate of itself is dangerous practice to begin with and can lead to reference cycles. You should consider refactoring your code to accomplish your task in a different way.